# What is "LSmi" and why it is using half of my RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory

My system (Windows 10, latest updates) has become increasingly unresponsive lately -- videos stutter during playback, context menus don't come up promptly, programs take a long time to launch, etc. The only thing abnormal I have noticed is that my memory usage now routinely sits at 50%, but I can't figure out what's using the memory.

It's not a memory leak -- the machine spikes to 3.9GB of memory right after boot, as soon as I'm able to open Task Manager it's already there. It's not the "System" or "Compressed Memory" features of Windows 10: the System process is using 0.1MB, and there is less than 500MB of compressed RAM. None of the other programs can account for it, either; if I add up everything in Task Manager I come to less than 500MB.

According to `poolmon`, all of the "missing" memory is coming from a single tag:

```
System pool information
Tag  Type     Allocs            Frees            Diff       Bytes                  Per Alloc

LSmi Paged  40351821 (3751)      1320 (   0) 40350501  3873648096 (     360096)          96
MmSt Paged   7696684 (  12)   7673507 (  13)    23177    56906496 (       5952)        2455
```

but I don't know what `LSmi` is. Is that a single process, or is it just some catch-all for "all the other stuff". Is there a way to figure out where that roughly 3.8 GB of memory is being used?

Comment: LSMi is storage used by components that implement the SMB (Server Message Block) protocol. This implements shared access to files and printers. However this is not likely using "half your RAM". Poolmon shows that this is in **paged** pool. Thus the  ~4GB you're seeing is a _virtual_ size; not all of it is necessarily in RAM (unless you have disabled your pagefile, which is almost always a terrible idea; this would be one reason). What does RAMmap show as the _physical_ usage of your paged pool? ...all that said, 4 GB of virtual alloc by Windows file and print sharing still seems excessive.

Comment: ok. so rammap says that 1.7GB is my pagefile and 1.3GB is the paged pool... so Windows Task Manager is including all of that in the "used" number and I really only have ~1GB in use, is that how I should interpret this? So there's something else unrelated to memory pressure causing my performance issues?

Comment: um... RAMmap doesn't actualyl have a display for "pagefile". Are you looking at the "page table" row? Anyway, please post screenshots of RAMmap's "Use Counts" tab and of Task Manager 's Performance tab, Memory page. And don't forget to run RAMmap as admin.